# Telerik Gantt chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I have 2 problems

1. Dynamically generated JSON object (jsonString) is empty in kendo.data.GanttDataSource.
   How do I call the dataSource.read() here ?

```js
var jsonObj = []; var jsonString = null;
$(document).ready(function () {
 var url = test.siteUrl() + "/_vti_bin/omg/tt.svc/Read/" + _campaign.CampaignWebID + "/" + _campaign.CampaignListID + "/" + _campaign.ID + "?t=" + of360.t();
 
 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {    
  $.each(data, function (i) {
  
  item = {}
  item['ID'] = data[i].ID;
  item['ChannelDescription'] = data[i].ChannelDescription;
  item['Start'] = data[i].Start;
  item['End'] = data[i].End; 
  item['PercentageComplete'] = data[i].BriefingState/10;
  item['Name'] = data[i].Name;
  jsonObj.push(item);
  });
  jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
        //regex : Json remove quotes
  jsonString = jsonString.replace(/"(\w+)"\s*:/g, '$1:');
  //alert(jsonString);
  
 });
});

var ganttModel = kendo.observable({  
 cancel: function () {
  this.cancelDialog();
 }, 
 isVisible: true,               
 ganttDS: new kendo.data.GanttDataSource({
  data: jsonString,
  schema: {
   model: {   
     id: "id",   
    fields: {
     Id: { from: "ID", type: "number" },
     start: { from: "BriefingStart", type: "date"},                                
     end: { from: "BriefingEnd", type: "date" },
     title: { from: "BriefingChannelDescription", type: "string" }, 
     PercentageComplete: {from:"PercentageComplete", type: "number"}
    }
   }
  }  
 })
});
```

2. How do I activate the toolbar export to PDF in my template ? my try did not work 
   data-toolbar="[""pdf""]"
                                   data-pdfExport="true"

```html
<script id="ganttChartTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div id="ganttchart"> 
<div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
     <div data-role="gantt"
        data-columns="[    
          { field: 'title', title: 'Gattung', width: 100 },        
          { field: 'start', title: 'Start Time', format: '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}', width: 100 },
          { field: 'end', title: 'End Time', format: '{0:dd/MM/yyyy}', width: 100 }          
         ]"
        data-views="[ 'day', { type: 'week', selected: true }, 'month' , 'year']"
        data-show-work-hours="true"
        data-show-work-days="true"
        data-height="300"
        data-editable="false"
        data-listWidth="600"
        data-toolbar="[""pdf""]" 
        data-pdfExport="true"        
        data-bind="source: ganttDS"></div>
    </div>
         </div>
   <div class="k-dialog-buttons modal-footer">      

        <button class="k-button k-primary" data-bind="events: { click: cancel }">#= Resources.OF360.SendToBuyingDialogCancel#</button>
  
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</script>
```

I appreciate your help here.

Answer (score 1):

1. unfortunately jsonObj did not work, I even tried with ganttDS.read() to assert it again. nothing worked.
   I solved this by using parse

```js
 parse: function (response) {   
            $.each(response, function (idx, elem) {                    
                var state = elem.BriefingState;
                   elem.BriefingState = state/11;
            });
            return response;
        }
```

2. data-toolbar="['pdf']" still did not work, I also tried it as a array of string with flower brackets.
   I solved it by calling the function itself in my model

```js
savePdf : function(){
  var gantt = $("#gantt").data("kendoGantt");
  gantt.saveAsPDF();
 },
```